# Make a dropdown visible on check box click in mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

I have a check box. On this checkbox's click i want to make a drop down visible. the code is as follows

```
<div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="SchoolAdmin" value="True" id="schooladmin">I would like to register as a school admin<br>
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("school", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Please select", Value = "-1" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="School1", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="School2", Value = "0" }
        })
    </div>
```

and the script for the above is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.schooladmin').is(":checked")) {
        //show the hidden div
        $('#school').show("fast");
    } else {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $('#school').hide("fast");
    }
    $('.schooladmin').click(function () {
        // If checked
        if ($('.schooladmin').is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $('#school').show("fast");
        } else {
            //otherwise, hide it and reset value
            $('#school').hide("fast");
            $('#school').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Anybody there to help me out pls...

Comment: `if ($('.schooladmin') {...` You dont have an element with a class name = schooladmin. I think you mean `$('#schooladmin')`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i did as u mentioned but still the changes is not effected

Comment: Have a look at the demo fiddle by shuanakde below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.schooladmin` is an ID and you're applying class selector to it, Try ID selector `#` for the same

So write

```
if($('#schooladmin').is(":checked") // add #
```

instead of

```
if ($('.schooladmin').is(":checked") // remove .
```

Everywhere

Your code should be like this:

```
$('#schooladmin').click(function () {
    if (this.checked)
        $('#school').show("fast");
    else
        $('#school').hide("fast");      
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mx3N/)

Comment: I did as u mentioned but no change is effected

Comment: Did you check my fiddle demo? mentioned in the answer!

Comment: @Dhaval yes. the same i copied and tried but didnt work.

Comment: @SajnaAli It should work, Press `F12` and click on console tab for errors in your browser and see what it says?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak yes its showing error ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @SajnaAli You have to include jQuery library for resolving that error as that is the basic process and most important thing to get these things done! :)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Thank you all...  i added the following and it worked
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `$('#schooladmin')` and not `$('.schooladmin')`. ***schooladmin*** is an **id** not a **class**.

and use

```
$('#schooladmin').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        //show the hidden div
        $('#school').show("fast");
    } else {
        //otherwise, hide it and reset value
        $('#school').hide("fast");
        $('#school').val('');
    }
});
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/yaku4/)**

Comment: i did as u mentioned but the change is not effected. What are the js files that i should include in the project?

Comment: Use latest jQuery file versions, **[Download](http://jquery.com/download/)**. Check console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#schooladmin').on("change", function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked")){

       }else{

       }
   }).trigger("change")
});
```